How to populate the 'Code' field of the VS 2022 Error List when writing a VS Extension?
I'm writing an extension for Visual Studio 2022 using the Community.VisualStudio.Toolkit package and part of my extension writes errors to the Error List window. I've figured out how to populate all the other fields I want (Severity, Description, Project, and Line) but I can't quite figure out how to write to the Code field.
I created an ErrorListProvider object from the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell package that I then add error messages to like so:
errorListProvider.Tasks.Add(new ErrorTask
{
    ErrorCategory = TaskErrorCategory.Warning,
    Text = error.Message,
    Document = error.FileName,
    Line = error.Line - 1, // error list uses 0 based indexing 
    Column = error.Column,
    HierarchyItem = hierarchy, // populates the 'Project' field in the error list
});

The only other fields that I can modify on the ErrorTask item are HelpKeyword and Category, which don't seem to affect the Code field.

Hi @jordanb, did you read
the doc StandardTableKeyNames Class from package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Framework?

@DouXu-MSFT , this worked, thanks!

Glad to hear that this issue doesn't block you anymore. Happy coding :D

@DouXu-MSFT Thanks! If you have a moment I was wondering if it is possible to also populate the "Details" column? The documentation lists a DetailsExpander field but implementing this doesn't seem to populate that column

I accomplished this by making a class that implements ITableEntry and has a member variable errorCode
public bool TryGetValue(string keyName, out object content)
{
    switch (keyName)
    {
        case StandardTableKeyNames.ErrorCode:
            content = errorCode;
            return true;
        default:
            content = "";
            return false;
    }
}

public bool CanSetValue(string keyName)
{
    switch (keyName)
    {
        case StandardTableKeyNames.ErrorCode:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

list.Add(new MyErrorListEntry()
{
    errorCode = error.Code
});


Try to use the following code:
errorListProvider.Tasks.Add(new ErrorTask
{
    ErrorCategory = TaskErrorCategory.Warning,
    // Code field
    Code = error.ErrorCode,
});

For more information, please read documents:
StandardTableKeyNames Fields
ErrorCode Field
